# How to make Android screenshots saved as .jpg?

Tags: android, screenshot, exif

I am using ExifInterface to save information for image description. But because screenshots are save .png and ExifInterface doesn't work on .png, I cannot save image description for screenshots.

I have two options:

1. Every time I need to save EXIF image description, I need to first convert the screenshots to .jpg format, and then edit its EXIF data.
2. Or I can just set the phone to save all screenshots as .jpg files. So whenever I save a screenshot (by pressing the volume down key+power button), the screenshot is saved right there and then as .jpg. No hassle trying to convert it later.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: `Or I can just set the phone to save all screenshots as .jpg files. ` ?? Can you? How? And what does it have to do with programming?

Comment: Have you tried the provided answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of a View's drawing cache.

```
myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/some/location/image.jpg"))
```

Where `view` is your View. The `95` is the quality of the JPG compression. And the file output stream is just that.

Comment: This works only if I am taking screenshots of my app. What about when I need to take a screenshot of  an app that I have no control over?

Comment: You are building screen grabber app. Use broadcast service to capture such event and return it as an intent to your app

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jaredco.screengrabber8&hl=en_US I saw this app that captures screenshot using a transparent button you can drag around. Can I configure physical buttons to capture screenshots?

Comment: The transparent button is a widget. You can create a widget and let `BroadcastService` handle event that your app requires.

Comment: Could you find any tutorial on make a complete screen grabber app? Most tutorials are about taking screenshot of one's own app. Thank you for the help thus far.

Comment: That is another question, and not for comment box. You can simply ask new  question again. Mind you, according to your question, my provided answer is the correct one.  You can simply mark it as answer to help others looking for similar solutions.